# Environment variable not working for 64 bit alone

Tags: java

I am using Windows10 64 bit , I have installed Java (JRE 64 bit & JDK 64 bit) in my machine.
I have file located in `C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\Hello.Class` 
but when I run my program using command `java Hello`.

I get the error message `Error: Could not find or load main class Hello`

Whereas when i install Java 32 bit , its working fine. The Problem occurs only for my Java 64 bit

The Environment variable configuration for Java 64 bit is as follows:

[image]

I have tried various solutions , none of them worked out . Please suggest any solution.

Comment: Add the Desktop folder to the `CLASSPATH`. Or (assuming you're in the desktop folder) run with `java -cp . Hello`

Comment: From where, you are executing this command "java Hello"?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i wanted to set it permenanetly,it works for java -cp . Hello temporarily

Comment: @SureshSajja From the location "C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop"

Comment: @saka1029 i dont use package in this program .Its a simple Hello world program.

Comment: Check Java folder location on both "Program files" folder and set it on class path

Comment: @MohitSharma Ya i have set the Classpath and please refer my image attached ,whether anything is wrong

Answer (score 1):

That's a silly place to put a .class file. Put into your current working directory.

I haven't set a CLASSPATH environment variable for about 20 years, and the contents of yours does not need to include the various `bin` directories.

Comment: i am currently doing that only ,but the number of files are more,so it became clumsy thats why i am in need of environmental variable

Comment: But, I repeat, you don't need the `bin` directories in it. There are no classes in or under a JDK or JRE `bin` directory. This is *wrong.* What you should really be doing is building JAR files with Main-class and Class-path manifest entries.